# How do I update Apache on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: linux, apache, centos6.5

I've spent all day searching Google and trying every command I could find or even think of to update Apache on my server.  I am running CentOS 6.5 64 bit.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled just to get the same outdated version.  I run the command yum update httpd and it runs through the list of repositories and says there are no updates found.  I know the newest update is 2.4.10 but I'm having the dangdest time trying to get that version to either update from current version or install with new installation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Apache 2.4.10 is the latest version from Apache, it is not the latest version in Centos 6.5.  On CentOS 6.5 the latest version is 2.2.15.  If you really want Apache 2.4 you need to add a repo that contains it.  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138899/centos-install-using-yum-apache-2-4) for an example

Comment: While the commands work to download the repository when I run the command yum install httpd24.x86_64 I get the following output "Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 base: ftpmirror.your.org
 epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 extras: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
 remi: mirror.pw
 updates: mirror.millry.co
 webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Package httpd24-1-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@GTS001DEVSWS yum.repos.d]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)"

Comment: The newer version doesn't install

Comment: I suspect you didn't follow all the steps on the question linked.  Using those directions you will have both apache 2.2 and 2.4 installed, but in different locations.  Running httpd -version alone will pick up whatever httpd is in your PATH, which will almost certainly be the default 2.2 that comes with CentOS.  The 2.4 version of httpd will located at /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd

Comment: Yes, I installed both versions and got exactly what you described.  I just simply uninstalled the other one and that took care of versioning